# Obtain other user followers from Instagram API without other users' access token

Tags: access-token, instagram-api

Hi I am asking this question because most of the related questions were before the update from Instagram.

Instagram has removed the console as well as restricting user to have access to other users' (lets call it A) content basically. Examples are like having to submit a review to obtain permissions to extract the data. I have a task to do, which is to extract other user's number of followers. I would like to avoid submitting the review as the client was a dummy account, just created to get the access token.

I managed to obtain my account's access token, but I am unable to use it to extract the information of the user A's number of followers. I could only extract my own number of followers/following etc only.

Are there any suggestions? Thank you!

Edit: User A account is public.